# Selecting a column from the array

Tags: c#, arrays

Can I extract an array from jagged /or 2 dim array ?
For example

```
int[,] arr = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
```

I would like to get `{1,3,5}`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can generate it.

To example:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    list.Add(arr[i,x];
```

where x is a needed *column*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a little bit of LINQ :

```
int[,] arr = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } };
var firstDim = arr.OfType<int>().Where((t, i) => i % 2 == 0); //1,3,5
var secondDim = arr.OfType<int>().Where((t, i) => i % 2 == 1); //2,4,6
```

Basically you flatten your multidimensional array and then pick alternating elements.